# There is a missing return statement, but the return statement is there?

Tags: java

I have a if/else loop nested in a for loop, this code says that it is missing a return statement:

```
  public int size()
  {
      //Count until you find a place in the array that is empty, then return the number
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i ++)
      {
          count ++;
          if (theArray[i] == 0)
          {
              return count;
          }
          else
          {
                 return 0;
          }
      }
  }
```

But, if i move the return statment like this:

```
  public int size()
  {
      //Count until you find a place in the array that is empty, then return the number
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i ++)
      {
          count ++;
          if (theArray[i] == 0)
          {
              return count;
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

the error goes away,but it doesn't give the correct count.

Comment: there are three cases in your code. you have handled only two cases in if and else .What if  theArray.length is 0 then it will not enter in the for loop and returned back . for that case one more return statement is required after for loop.

Comment: Why do you need both `i` and `count`? This algorithm seems suspect.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your last question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at Java, and i keep having new problems.@ScaryWombat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `theArray.length` is zero, then the body of the loop won't be executed at all and no return statement will be executed.

Also, your logic seems a little weird and there seems no reason for a local `count` variable. First, you have to decide what the method should return if there are no empty spaces or if the array has no spaces at all (length 0). I suggest returning `-1` for both those cases. If the goal is to return the index of the first empty space (which will also be the count of the number of non-empty spaces before the first space), you might try:

```
public int size(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: @AlaynaJuneau - I updated my answer with some suggested code.

Comment: @TedHopp well explained !

Answer (score 2):

If 'theArray' is of size 0, there will be no return statement in your first example.

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: Put another return statement outside the for loop as you did in your second example. One that deals with the 0 size array.